# Powershell - how to only apply foreach to distinct values that are returned from a T-SQL query

Tags: powershell, t-sql, foreach

I am very new to powershell - currently using it to output PDF files from our EHR which runs on a SQL server database.

Within my powershell function, I have a tsql query which returns multiple rows for the same event. An event may contain multiple questions which each can have multiple answers - thus creating multiple rows for each event in the t-sql query results.
I'll post my pshell function code at the bottom (minus the actual t-sql query)
My tsql test query is returning these results:
[t-sql query results for test event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPoB8.png)

And on the PDF output, I want the output to look like this:
Event: Face to Face - FPS Test
Date: 3/2/2021
Answers:
Faith Support
Narcotics Anonymous (NA)
Test
Answers:
Note_text:
test

Event: Phone Call (Other)
Date: 3/3/2021
Note_text:
testing second event

By separating the t-sql query into different queries, I can get the questions to output with multiple answers just fine, and I can get a list of events to output as well, but it breaks when I try to combine the two. I end up with something like this:

[image: current results]

It's splitting out a new entry for each answer to the 'community connection' question rather than creating a list.

Is there a way to use the foreach in powershell to look at the distinct event_log_ids that are returned from the t-sql query instead of using foreach($row in $table.rows)? In the cases with multiple rows for a single event, each row related to the same event would have the same event_log_id.

pshell function code: `function Get-MonthlyReport-ServiceNotes-FPS([string]$templatePath,[string]$pplid,[string]$programenrollmentid,[string]$fdom,[string]$ldom){
$dbconn = ($ConfigFile.Settings.DBCONN_EVOLV);

```
    # html template
    $templateFilename = "$($templatePath)\mr_segment_servicenotes - FPS.html";
    $htmltemplate = Get-HTMLTemplate -htmlfilename $templateFilename;
    $htmlbody = '';

    # sql query - returns columns actual_date, event_name, note_text, answer, and event_log_id
    
    
    Try
    {
        $connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($dbconn);
        $command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlquery,$connection);
        $command.CommandTimeout=0;
        $connection.Open();
        $adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command;
        $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
        $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null;
        $connection.Close();
        $table = $dataset.Tables[0]
        $eventLogList = @($dataset.Tables[0] | select-object -Property event_log_ids | Sort-Object | Get-unique)
        

        # default content
        $htmlcontent = $htmltemplate;

        if($dataset.Tables[0].Rows.count -gt 0){         

            # add content
            foreach($row in $table.rows) {    
        
                
                # remove HTML tags and formatting from note_text
                if (-not ("$($row.note_text)" -eq $null)) {
                    $ntxt = Remove-HTMLTags -html "$($row.note_text)";
                    $htmlbody += "<tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<td style=`"font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;`">Service:<br>$($row.event_name)</td>";
                    $htmlbody += "</tr>"; 
                    $htmlbody += "<tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<td style=`"font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;`">event_log_id:<br>$($row.event_log_ids)</td>";
                    $htmlbody += "</tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<td style=`"font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;`">Date:<br>$($row.actual_date)</td>";
                    $htmlbody += "</tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<td style=`"font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;`">Community Connection:<br>$($row.answer)</td>";
                    $htmlbody += "</tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<tr>";
                    $htmlbody += "<td style=`"font-size: 9pt;`">$($ntxt)<br>"
                    $htmlbody += "<hr style=`"border-top: dotted 1px;`" /></td>";
                    $htmlbody += "</tr>";
                    
            
                    
                 
                }
            }

            # assemble html
            if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($htmlbody))) { 
                 $htmlcontent = $htmlcontent.Replace("{{table-set}}",$($htmlbody));
            } else {
                $nodata = "<tr><td style=`"font-size: 9pt;`" colspan=`"3`">No service notes were provided during this period.</td><tr>";
                $htmlcontent = $htmlcontent.Replace("{{table-set}}",$($nodata));
            } 

        } else {

             #if no data is returned
            $nodata = "<tr><td style=`"font-size: 9pt;`" colspan=`"3`">No service notes were provided during this period.</td><tr>";
            $htmlcontent = $htmlcontent.Replace("{{table-set}}",$($nodata));
        }

        # return string
        return $htmlcontent; 
    }
    Catch
    {
        $me = "Get-MonthlyReport-ServiceNotes-FPS";
        $msg = $_.Exception.Message;
        Put-EventLog -key "ERROR" -eventtype "PROCESS" -eventsource $me -description $msg;
        throw $_.Exception; 
    } 
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the IDs, that's trivial in SQL with `DISTINCT`.

In Powershell you could do something like this to get the list.

```
$SqlResults | Select-Object -Property event_log_ids | Sort-Object -Unique
```

EDIT: If you're on SQL Server 2016+ you can use the STRING_AGG function to merge the answers into a list upstream.

```
select actual_date
--other fields
, string_agg(Answer, ', ') as AnswerCommaSeparated
, string_agg(Answer, char(13)+char(10)) as AnswerNewLineSeparated
from SomeTable
group by actual_date
```

Comment: Getting the IDs in t-sql isn't a problem, it's trying to get powershell to only give one output per event log id rather than duplicating everything for each new row - I updated my initial question with a screen shot of my results for clarity. the highlighted sections should all fall under one list rather than being split out. I was hoping by getting a list of distinct event_log_ids I could use foreach over that instead of each row

Comment: Could you please post your code and expected results in the question. I'm guessing it should be something like a hash table with id as key and an array of answers per id, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Just updated the question with the function code and expected results. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately we are not on sql server 2016 yet. That is good to know for the future... I may try to get my sql code to do something similar if that's the only solution.